# How to ignore Servlet Filters for public resources (.js .css files)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a **spring boot** project with a **JWT Filter** in the the security configuration. Basically this filter extracts the jwt token from the request and add the Principal to the SecurityContext.

I also have **static files** (.css / .js / .ttf ...) in the folder `src/main/resources/static`, so I can access the files without authentication.

It works perfectly, but before serving theses files it executes the jwt filter which is **useless** because I don't need to extract the jwt token for these requests. It takes some extra milliseconds for nothing.

I would like to ignore the jwt filter for the static resources.

I ended up with this solution : overriding the **configure method** in the spring security configuration

```
@Override
public void configure( WebSecurity web ) throws Exception
{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/**/*.js", "/**/*.css" );
}
```

Now when I request a js file, the filter is no longer executed. The main problem here is to list all the **ant pattern** for the static resources (images/fonts/audio...).

Is there a better solution to resolve this problem rather than listing all the static files extensions in the configure method ?

Comment: Place them in a separate folder e.g. `static` and use `antMatchers( "/static/*.*");`

Comment: maybe `/static/**/*.*` would be better

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

`web.ignoring().antMatchers( "/**/*.*" );`

Comment: yes this can works, to be more secure I think I will put my resources in a specifi folder and use `/specific-folder/**/*.*`